# How to internationalise @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{10})") in bean validation?

Tags: bean-validation, valdr-bean-validation

I am using bean validation to validate my entity,
it works fine according to different locales and it shows region-specific error messages, but I want to internationalize a field 'ContactNo' according to the region like my error messages `@NotBlank(message="{contactNo.size}")`.

So how to achieve

```
@Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{10})")
private String contactNo;`
```

where the regexp value changes according to the region?

Comment: Any further feedback needed here? Is it solved?

Comment: @MarcelStör please you can suggest me further about this.

Comment: There is nothing more I could add to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The the value for the `regexp` attribute has to be constant i.e. it needs to be available at compile time. So, either it needs to be a string literal as you do now or externalized into a `static final` variable.

I guess what you need has to be implemented in a [custom Bean Validation constraint](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).